# Is there a way to "shift click" to select several vertex groups at once and then click "select" just once?

Tags: interface, vertex-groups

So I have a model with about a hundred vertex groups. If I want to select the vertices of multiple vertex groups I have to click on the vertex group, then move my mouse over to "select" to click it, and then move my mouse back to the list of vertex groups to click on the next group and so forth.

Is there a way I can select multiple vertex groups at once such as shift-clicking vertex groups to select all of the groups in a certain range? (the same way you can easily select multiple things in the Outliner).

That way I only have to press "select" once instead of dozens of times. If there is no built in solution I'm open to scripts or add ons as well.

Here is a picture of the process I must repeat dozens of times for reference:

[image]

Comment: Wow it will be awesome once they implement selecting vertex groups in Outliner! Until then, one slightly easier way is to right click "Select" and Add to Quick Favorites. Then you can highlight a group, press Q to bring up Quick Favorites, and click Select. The other way would be a python script; in my brief search I have not found anything.

Comment: Not the "solution" but that definitely speeds things up! Thanks! The reason you say "once they implement..." is because there are currently plans to implement that? or are you assuming they eventually will?

Comment: You are welcome. Literally if you try to select vertex groups in Outliner it says "Not yet implemented" at the bottom of the screen. Until then, maybe there's a robust add-on that can help with this. I will look once more.

Comment: Oh I see, I had seen that message before but I didn't realize what it meant, thanks. If you do find an add one please let me know!

Comment: I did another search but have not found a solution. This add-on helps switch between and even lock vertex groups for weight painting (useful in full screen mode): https://blenderartists.org/t/popup-vertex-group-list-weight-paint/1115471 I think there is a way to hack the python script and add a "select vertices" function for each button.

Comment: If you are interested, you can see more about python for "vertex_group_select" here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select

Answer (score 1):

You can't shift select vertex Groups,
but you can apply any weights filter to all vertex groups at once.

Go to weight paint mode and apply a 'Smooth Vertex Weights' Filter E.g.
In the small dialog that pops up select 'All Groups' as a Subset instead of the default 'Active Group'.

[image]